# How to handle nulls in a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, dbnull

My page is have issues because some columns values in a row are NULL, how can I only display the value if it is NOT NULL?

```
 <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><%# Eval("some_db_column") %></td>
                </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Try Eval("column") ?? string.Empty

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<%#Eval("some_db_column") ?? "" %>
```

[?? Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

If that's not working, you can also call a method in codebehind:

```
protected string GetValue(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || DBNull.Value.Equals(obj))
    {
       return String.Empty;
    }

    return obj.ToString();
}
```

aspx:

```
<%# GetValue(Eval("some_db_column")) %>
```

Comment: the first option you have doesn't seem to work: <%#Eval("some_db_column") ?? "" %>

Comment: @user1361315: Maybe because it's `DBNull.Value` instead. So you could try `<%#Eval("some_db_column")==DBNull.Value ? "" : Eval("some_db_column")%>` or the codebehind approach which is better anyway.